# Eight people are given a fair coin and each tosses the coin until they land a tails. What's the probability that nth toss is the final toss?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand how the sample space and probabilities for a problem like this would look. Starting with the basics, each person having a probability of 0.5 for tossing a tails for the first toss. For the second toss, each person having a probability of 0.75 (HH, HT, TH, TT) of tossing a tails. I believe this would continue through n tosses as $1-p^n$ where $p=0.5$.

Now looking at the probabilities across all 8 people, the probability of each person tossing a tails after the first toss would be equal to tossing 8 consecutive tails, $0.5^8$.

Then what would be the probability that the second toss would be the last toss (i.e., all 8 people tossed a tails within the first two tosses), then the probability that the third toss would be the last toss, all the way through n tosses.

I've looked at the probability of tossing a tails after each toss, but this is always increasing and I suspect that eventually the probability of toss n being the last toss will start to decrease (say after 7 tosses) because of the high probability to land a tails in 6 tosses. Any insights into how I should be thinking about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just an FYI, this isn't a direct homework problem, but the answer to this will help me understand a concept to a sub-part of a homework problem. I'm not too sure what the rules are around that.

Comment: You could use $\LaTeX$ to make your expressions like $1-p^n$ instead of `1-p^n`.

Comment: *"n-th toss is the final toss"* does it mean that after $n$ global tosses you get the $8$-th tail ?

Comment: After $n$ global tosses, every person has tossed at least one tail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number the persons with $i=1,2,\dots,8$ and let $X_i$ denote the number of tosses that are needed for person $i$ to arrive at tails.

Then at stake is the distribution of:$$X:=\max\{X_1,\dots,X_8\}$$where the $X_i$ are iid random variables with geometric distribution equipped with parameter $p=0.5$.

Here for nonnegative integer $k$: $$
\begin{align} 
P(X\leq k)&=P(X_1\leq k,\dots, X_8\leq k)\\&=\prod_{i=1}^8P(X_i\leq k)\\&=P(X_1\leq k)^8\\&=[1-P(X_1>k)]^8\\&=(1-2^{-k})^8
\end{align} 
$$
enabling you to find for positive integer $k$: $$
\begin{align} 
P(X=k)&=P(X\leq k)-P(X\leq k-1)\\&=(1-2^{-k})^8-(1-2^{1-k})^8
\end{align} $$

Comment: Hi @drhab, thanks for this. I was able to get to the $(1-2^{-k})^8$ solution (not so formally), but was missing the subtraction of $(1-2^{1-k})^8$. Is there a concept or book that I can read about to understand this better?

Comment: If you are after finding $P(X=k)$ for integers $k$ and it appears to be not so easy then it is a good custom to go for finding $P(X\leq k)$ (or $P(X\geq k)$ which is easyer to find sometimes). We have: $$\{X\leq k\}=\{X\leq k-1\}\cup\{X=k\}$$ where the events on RHS are mutually exclusive so that:$$P(X\leq k)=P(X\leq k-1)+P(X=k)$$If that is clear to you by this then IMV you don't need a book to confirm it. Just put it in your pocket right now.